# CMD batch print pdf through Acrobat Reader DC

Tags: batch-file, pdf, command-line

I wish to print multiple PDF files in an alphabetical order,
these files are the lecture notes from MitOpenCourse :D
but "right click - print" option only seems to print them out in a random order.

So I tried to use a commandline using the following reference:
http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/pdf/intro_to_sdk/DeveloperFAQ.pdf
(Page 27)

> for %%X in (*.pdf) do "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /t %%X "\E06-02-4321\HP Officejet 7110 series"

So this is what I wrote in the batch file. But it does not seem to work. 
When I run the batch all it does is it opens up a acrobat reader and that's it.
The printer I am using - as you can see is HP Officejet 7110 and E06-02-4321 is my computer name.

I tried using echo and pause in the batch but it does not show any errors.

Help would be appreciated!
Chris

Comment: Network printer: `\\servername\HP Officejet 7110 series` (note the doubled \\ backslashes) . Local printer: `HP Officejet 7110 series`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AcroRd32.exe /t path "printername" "drivername" "portname"
```

> Initiates Adobe Reader and prints *a file, whose path must be fully
>   specified*, while suppressing the Print dialog box. The four
>   parameters of the `/t` option evaluate to `path`, `printername`,
>   `drivername`, and `portname` (all strings).
>
> - `printername` — The name of your printer.
> - `drivername` — Your printer driver’s name, as it appears in your printer’s properties.
> - `portname` — The printer’s port. portname cannot contain any "/" characters; if  it does, output is routed to the default port for that
>     printer.

IMHO the four parameters of the `/t` option are obligatory (not facultative) ones; hence, supply them as follows:

```
set "acrobat=C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"
set "printername=HP Officejet 7110 series"
set "drivername=HP Officejet 7110 series"
set "portname=USB001"
for %%X in (*.pdf) do "%acrobat%" /t "%%~fX" "%printername%" "%drivername%" "%portname%"
rem                                   %%~fX = fully qualified file name
```

Get actual values from `wmic path Win32_Printer get caption, drivername, portname` command or even from `wmic path Win32_Printer get /value` (scriptable using two nested `for /F` loops against `wmic` output).

Comment: Works! thanks a lot :)
Have to say though, AcroRD32 process this real slow. 
1 print out and then 30 sec later next one..